# Is WCF the right tool for this?

Tags: wcf

I am trying to setup WCF to accept urls with querystrings as parameters, but this is proving quite difficult. Is WCF the right tool for the job? Should I be using something like IHttpHandler instead?

The last problem I ran into was that it couldn't figure out which url template to use, because of the querystrings.

**Example URLs**

```
http://ww.somedomain.com?sessionid=123123&language=en&mode=true
http://ww.somedomain.com?sessionid=123123&language=en&mode=true&type=login
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I'm not sure why you would use a WCF service to do this. A custom HTTP Handler sounds more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using REST capabilities of WCF with webHttpBinding this should be easy. For url mapping you can use IIS 7 Url rewrite to compose any specific format url's